# ClamAV didn't see virus inside an Archive

Tags: anti-virus, clamav

/home/folder/clam_daily.sh: OK
/home/folder/.sudo_as_admin_successful: Empty file
/home/folder/.selected_editor: OK
/home/folder/PROTECTAgentInstaller.tar.gz: OK
/home/folder/.bash_logout: OK
/home/folder/report.html: OK
/home/folder/.profile: OK
**/home/folder/Win32.LuckyCat.zip: OK**

/home/folder/clamav-1.0.1.linux.x86_64.deb: OK
/home/folder/report.txt: OK
/home/folder/.bashrc: OK
/home/folder/PROTECTAgentInstaller.sh: OK

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 8669609
Engine version: 1.0.1
Scanned directories: 1
Scanned files: 11
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 29.11 MB
Data read: 13.81 MB (ratio 2.11:1)
Time: 23.086 sec (0 m 23 s)
Start Date: 2023:06:28 16:13:55
End Date: 2023:06:28 16:14:18

Comment: The problem is i know that there is a virus inside an archive. here /home/folder/Win32.LuckyCat.zip: OK    but the clamav says it`s OK! how can this be

Comment: How do you know it's there? What virus is it? Is it on their checklist?

Comment: Just guessing, maybe the file is just named like that and has only a few bytes and ClamAV isn't reporting a false positive? Has your question something to do with in example [debugging and testing](https://github.com/abes-esr/clamscan-docker/blob/main/README.md#debugging-and-testing)?

Comment: There a special WWW site where you can download and test the antivirus with unharmful viruses if i remember it called Eicar.org